# membershiprenewallink can't find membershiptype

Tags: drupal, civimember, php

everybody
Sorry if it's a newbie question, I hope you could help anyway.

My site (drupal 9 + civi + php 8.1) is actually working for anonymous users; as soon as a user login the WSoD appears (The website encountered an unexpected error).
Every time I visit the page with an authenticated user the WSoP appears and this is what comes up in the PHP error log (followed by the details):

```
Error: Class "Civi\Api4\MembershipType" not found in [path-to-files]/civicrm/ext/membershiprenewallink/settings/membershiprenewallink.setting.php on line 11
```

Even if I try to disable the extension via drush or cv I get this error:

```
In membershiprenewallink.setting.php line 11: Class 'Civi\Api4\MembershipType' not found
```

I think that I have some global configuration problems, but the site was up and running nd in production. From where I could start?
Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have CiviMember disabled on your site, so the [Membership Renewal Link](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/membershiprenewallink) extension crashes. Enable CiviMember. If you can't log in, you can do it from the command line:

```
cv en civi_member
```

Comment: Thank you, Coleman. I even tried to disable the extension Membership Renewal Link, but every time I issue a command (even the one that you suggested) I receive the error:
In membershiprenewallink.setting.php line 11: Class 'Civi\Api4\MembershipType' not found

Comment: You could try: cv dis membershiprenewallink to disable Membership Renewal Link, then enable civi_member, then after that re-enable Membership Renewal Link.